# Remove item from object where key is different for each entry

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am storing a list of key value pairs in Javascript where he key is different for each entry:

```
8f348f-b4d0-66bf-b0cj-a31b9c45c: "Pete"
ff5764-7863-6pc9-b72f-195f2h962: "Dave"
```

The key is the connection id of the connected session and the value is the username. I then want to remove an item from the list, being passed:

```
Key: "8f348f-b4d0-66bf-b0cj-a31b9c45c"
Value: "Dave"
```

I know that the key will be unique, but the value might not be.

I have tried:

```
var removedIndex = _.findIndex(usersConnected, function (item) {
     return item.key == connection.key;
});
```

but this returns -1 even when there should be a match. If this would work, I could remove the item as follows:

```
if (removedIndex > -1) {
    usersConnected.splice(removedIndex , 1);
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpNrda)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, you should just be able to do:

```
delete usersConnected[connection.Key];
```

This is assuming that `usersConnected` is in fact an object, and that `connection` looks like this:

```
{ Key: 'the-connection-id', Value: 'the value' }
```

Note that for runtime optimization it is often a better idea to set the value to `null` rather than delete:

```
usersConnected[connection.Key] = null;
```

But that's an optimization that is not relevant to your primary issue, included here mostly to quiet any best practices bulldogs. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`items` is `Object` not `Array`, and in `Object` there is no method `splice`, for delete item from `Object` use `delete items[item.key]`

```js
var items = {
  "8f348f-b4d0-66bf-b0cj-a31b9c45c": "Pete",
  "ff5764-7863-6pc9-b72f-195f2h962": "Dave"
}

var item = {
  key: "8f348f-b4d0-66bf-b0cj-a31b9c45c",
  value: "Pete"
}

delete items[item.key];

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your data in the codepen is not correct:

See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7ythry0/).

Your data should look like:

```
var items =    [{key: "8f348f-b4d0-66bf-b0cj-a31b9c45c", value: "Pete"}, {key: "ff5764-7863-6pc9-b72f-195f2h962", value: "Dave"}]
```

Not like:

```
var items =     {"8f348f-b4d0-66bf-b0cj-a31b9c45c": "Pete", "ff5764-7863-6pc9-b72f-195f2h962": "Dave"}
```

Your data should be an array of objects with "key" and "value" properties.